# Example of finitely generated A-module with $aM=M$ then there exists $x\equiv1 \pmod a$ and $xM=0$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Corollary 2.5 in Atiyah & MacDonald says if $a$ is an ideal in A-module with $aM=M$ then there exists $x\equiv1 \pmod a$ and $xM=0$.

What is an example of this if $A= \mathbb{Z}$ and $a=(n)$ then what does $ M$ have to be? I guess $M$ must be finitely generated.

I have tried with $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ and $n=(3)$. Then $\gcd(3,5) =1$ so $2\cdot3=1 \pmod 5$, but $3 \mathbb{Z}_{5} \neq 0$.

Comment: In your example, $M=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{a}=(3)$. So you should not have $3(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})=0$ but rather $3(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z},$ which is true. Then an $x$ with $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ that kills $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is e.g. $x=10$.